# Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

When Im trying to run `yarn run android` command I get the error below:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1365 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/oguzhanyildirim/Desktop/actimi-app/actimi-app/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/oguzhanyildirim/Desktop/actimi-app/actimi-app/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveNonArrayType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:70)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.MemberSignatureParser.createMethodNode(MemberSignatureParser.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode$2.get(DecompiledClassNode.java:234)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode$2.get(DecompiledClassNode.java:231)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.createMethodNode(DecompiledClassNode.java:242)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitMembers(DecompiledClassNode.java:199)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(DecompiledClassNode.java:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:912)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.tryFindPossibleMethod(ClassNode.java:1280)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:252)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:142)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:121)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticImportVisitor.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:128)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1099)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitClass(StaticImportVisitor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:708)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1084)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:640)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:618)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:595)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:401)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$300(GroovyClassLoader.java:89)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:341)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:338)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:336)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:95)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler$2.run(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:190)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:170)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:211)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:194)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:100)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:86)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:139)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:78)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:42)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:95)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:126)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:116)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.getOrCompile(CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.java:50)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.java:50)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:125)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:248)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:275)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:247)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:248)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:308)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:308)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:289)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:247)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:710)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:145)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:57)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:228)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:87)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
  
  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 13s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is the full error. I tried cleaning gradle with `./gradlew clean` then `yarn run android` but didnt work. I tried many ways from github or stack by using android studio terminal. I also tried **Clean Project** and **Rebuild Project** from ***Build tab*** on Anroid Studio but no result.

This is the main problem I think : `Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081`

I need an emergency help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it by following these steps:

1. Changed my `java --version` to **15.0.2**
2. Changed my **distributionUrl(./android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties directory)** to **6.7** like : `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip`
3. in ./android I ran `./gradlew clean`
4. in ./android I ran `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/`
5. in project folder I ran `react-native run-android` again

Comment: doens't work. do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure that `npx react-native doctor` has all been checked, and if you can run your project on Android Studio properly.

Then try `yarn android --variant=YOUR_VARIENT`.

ex: `yarn android --variant=GooglePlayDebug`

Hope this will be helpful.